# Collect EMG data over a period of time. Suggested JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, myo

I'm currently developing a web application that embed Thalmic Myo EMG.

I want to collect data in a period of time while my web app showing the time ticker and instructions to user.

Current problem is I don't know what type of JS that can provide this function. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer. gsap.js .

Click here to find out more about GSAP : http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/